# Trouble with mapply

Tags: r

I have a problem using the mapply function.

Basically there is one response vector "class" and a predictor matrix "pred".

```
class <-c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
pred  <-matrix(c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10)), ncol = 3)
```

What I want is to apply the function "llda" three times, each time using another column from the predictor matrix.

The function:

```
library(MASS)
llda<-function(class, pred){ 
sum(predict(lda(class~pred))$class==class)/length(class)
}
```

The result mapply shall deliver:

```
llda(class, pred[,1])
llda(class, pred[,2])
llda(class, pred[,3])
```

I transformed "class" and "pred" into lists. So that each column vector of "pred" became a seperate item of the list.

```
list(class)->class
split(pred, col(pred))->pred
```

When I now try to use mapply I get an error.

```
mapply(llda(class, pred), class = class, pred = pred)
```

However, this is working:

```
llda(class[[1]],pred[[1]])
llda(class[[1]],pred[[2]])
llda(class[[1]],pred[[3]])
```

Shouldn't mapply do the same? Taking the first element of each list and save this. Then taking the second of pred and since class has only one element, this is recycled.

I cannot figure out myself what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `mapply(llda, class = class, pred = pred)` work?

Comment: Oh, yes. That was the whole problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapply(llda, class = class, pred = pred)` will work. You just need to give `mapply` the function and the list(s) of objects to iterate over. The code you had is incorrect,  because it will evaluate `llda(class, pred)`, and the return of that is not itself a function, so the `mapply` will fail.